# lock screen on resume

Tags: 18.04, suspend, plasma, lock

I have Ubuntu 18.04 with Plasma installed and I have `Lock screen on resume:` checked under `System Settings` -> `Desktop Behavior` -> `Configure Screen Locking` but when I put my computer to sleep by `K-Menu` -> `Leave` -> `Suspend`, I can wake it up and am brought back right where I left off, bypassing the lock screen altogether. How come? What am I missing?

Thank you